# Are my AWS CloudWatch Metrics Insights queries limited to 3 hours worth of data in all cases? Is it the same with Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I have been working with cloudwatch insights for a while now. I have built some dashboards based around metrics insights queries.

It appears I have misunderstood how this works. My Metrics Insights queries are all limited to 3 hours when I graph them. I thought this limitation only applied to metrics that were pushed at a higher frequency than every 5 minutes, but apparently that's not the case.

Am I correct in my thinking that ALL metrics insights queries are limited to 3 hours if I use things like filtering and `GROUP BY` in my queries?

So essentially any query where I want to use dimensions will have this limitation, and if I want to query for longer time periods I need to create multiple metrics that include my dimensions as part of the name instead of as dimensions. Is that correct?

As I understand it, Prometheus doesn't work this way, does it? I could query metrics/dimensions over say a 24 hour period with Prometheus, right?